# Errors with files compile in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

In advance I regret for my English.
I have a problem when i `run ng build --prod` in Angular project. Return this errors.
ERROR in Error: Error: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined
        at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js)
        at tokenExpr (node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js)
        at providerDef (node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js)
        at node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js
        at Array.map (native)
        at NgModuleCompiler.compile (node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js)
        at AotCompiler._compileModule (node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js)
        at node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at AotCompiler._compileImplFile (node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js)
        at node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js
        at Array.map (native)
        at AotCompiler.emitAllImpls (node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js)
        at AngularCompilerProgram.generateFilesForEmit (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js)
        at AngularCompilerProgram.emit (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js)
        at AngularCompilerPlugin._emit (node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js)

My package.json

```
{
    ...
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
        "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
        ...
    }
}
```

When i start ng serve or ng build no errors.
Who had this problem, tell me how it can be solved.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: please format your relevant errors and add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

When using `ng-package` to publish a repository, the `repo's` root directory shouldn't contain any dist/ directory, which means that all the final `.js & .es5.js` files should exist on the root directory of the published repository.

Suppose you have a repository named `myRepo`, then the final hierarchy should be similar to this:

```
---myRepo
---------myRepo.js
---------myRepo.es5.js
---------bundles/
---------src/ (contains definition files for components, services, etc)
```

When using myRepo in any other project, that is the case here, all the imports should be similar to this:

```
import {myService} from 'myRepo'
import {myModule} from 'myRepo'
```

Now, if you run `ng build --prod`, you must not face any error.

Please take a look at the [reference](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/266)

Answer (score 0):

Try into project at the console  to make npm install this would install the last packages maybe there is the problem, when you make this it will update all packages to lastest version.